# What is the support lifetime for Ubuntu Core?

Tags: upgrade, lts, snap, ubuntu-core

None of the information I can find about [Ubuntu Core](https://www.ubuntu.com/core) mentions how long each release is supported for. The [end of life](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) page, and the [releases wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), make no mention of Ubuntu Core.

Does it follow the base Ubuntu LTS support schedule? i.e. is Ubuntu Core 16 going to be supported with security updates until 2021? (same as 16.04 LTS) Or, when Core 18 comes out will Core 16 systems be upgraded with the "Core" snap, and effectively become Core 18 systems and so on, hence receiving indefinite updates?

Comment: intresting.. since I was able to find images for 15.04 I don't think they have the same LTS support schedule. However, since Ubuntu Core gets **almost everything** from snaps, even the kernel, I don't think it has to.

Comment: The whole point of Ubuntu Core is that your device should be updating automatically. So only one 'release' is supported: The current snap. It is updated as-needed, not scheduled. Think of it as a rolling flavor for devices.

Comment: How does that come into play with model assertions? https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/reference/assertions/model If the model assertion says `series: "16"`, as in https://assertions.ubuntu.com/v1/assertions/model/16/canonical/pi3, how does that combine with the rolling releases?